# Scipy Interpolate function not recognized

Tags: python, import, module, scipy, interpolation

I created a program to do some calculations, part of that is an interpolation. For some reason the program is not capable of loading scipy interpolate module. How can I make it work? The path to the scipy interpolate module is right.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interplt
ftempacce = interplt(temp, acce, kind='linear')
ait = ftempacce(t)
```

Log Error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interplt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from .interpolate import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 467
    ait        if self.bounds_error and below_bounds.any():
                                                          ^
```

Variables temp and acce are lists of numbers:

```
>>> type(temp)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(acce)
<type 'list'>
>>>
```

Comment: I can't see the function you want to import listed here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html

Comment: After reading teh manual I found the mistake in my code. It should read "interpld" instead of "interplt". Its been a silly typing mistake. Thanks for pointing to the reference manual Hemmer2